# Linux: How to strip actual data apart from header and trailer

Tags: linux

I have a file which has data contains headers(some message) , actual data and then trailer(with some message) I want to strip only the actual data.

I found the below command which does the purpose.

sed -n '/.*[0-9]{9}.*[0-9]{10}.*/p' abc.txt>abc_new.txt

file looks like this.

Mc38749-001                                                Set Up Process                                            Page:           86
Tax Services                                    Cancellation and Exception Process                                   Run Date: 01/30/12
Source  :   52A   abc compnany                                Detail  Report                                         Run Time: 03:24:27
Customer: 438540 abc company

```
            Bus.      Order    Order                           Srvc Loan Excptn
```

Count  State  Source    Number     Date       Loan Id     Request Type Type  Code                            Message

---

```
  1 AB              354039865 11/30/18 34547896      1       C         S01    Needs Legal -  System Suspension
```

Mc38749-001                                                Set Up Process                                            Page:           87
Tax Services                                    Cancellation and Exception Process                                   Run Date: 01/30/12
Source  :   52A   abc compnany                                Detail  Report                                         Run Time: 03:24:27
Customer: 438540 abc company

```
            Bus.      Order    Order                           Srvc Loan Excptn
```

Count  State  Source    Number     Date       Loan Id     Request Type Type  Code                            Message

---

I want the data in the file like this.(its a single line)

1 AB              354039865 11/30/18 34547896      1       C         S01    Needs Legal -  System Suspension

Can any of you please decode what this does.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think you could edit that jumble again? I can't make too much sense of your `file` ...

Answer (score 0):

It may work that just to grep on certain number of white space characters between 1 and AB and stream it to new file.